# Problems with a legacy TFS project collection after migration to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-server-2020

We have an on-premise Azure DevOps server (v2020) that had originally been a TFS server, migrated a couple of years ago. As the team has expanded, we would now like to start using more of the agile/scrum features but I'm noticing some problems, one of which is this error message on the "Taskboard" tab of the "Sprints" page:

> Sorry, something went wrong - Parent Backlog level not found for Microsoft.RequirementCategory

I can only assume there is some incompatibility within the project collection (originally created when it was TFS) since migrating the database to DevOps. Any thoughts on what the problem might be, e.g. something in one of the WIT XML files?

I can't remember which process the projects in this collection were created with, but probably would have been one of the "MSF for Agile..." options. If I go into `Collection Settings -> Projects`, the "Process" column is blank for all projects, and I don't get the option to change a project's process either. If I go to the `Collection Settings -> Process` page, I see: Basic, Agile, Scrum, CMMI, plus several "MSF..." options with `</>` alongside (which are presumably those migrated from when it was TFS).

I'm guessing some of these issues I'm seeing relate to the "inherited process model vs hosted XML" thing, which I confess to not really understanding.

Comment: This link may help identify the process used when a project was created: "[Correlate a process template with an existing project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#correlate-a-process-template-with-an-existing-project)"